# inspectdb on MySQL throws exceptions

Tags: python, mysql, django, inspectdb

I'm trying to run inspectdb and getting connection does not exist error! I have a database by name myapp in MySQL along with other databases.

This is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'myapp',
    'USER': '*****',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
    'HOST': 'ec2-11-111-111-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '8000',
    }
}
```

Project structure:

```
mysite/
   manage.py
   mysite/
       settings.py
```

This is what happens:

> root@ip-10-202-209-99:~/Desktop/mysite# python manage.py inspectdb
>   --database myapp
>           Traceback (most recent call last): 
>             File "manage.py", line 10, in 
>               execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django
>   /core/management/**init**.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
>               utility.execute() 
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 392, in execute
>               self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 242, in run_from_argv 
>               self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**) 
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 285, in execute
>               output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 415, in handle
>               return self.handle_noargs(**options)
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py",
>   line 27, in handle_noargs
>               for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py",
>   line 33, in handle_inspection
>               connection = connections[options.get('database')] 
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 196, in **getitem** 
>               self.ensure_defaults(alias)
>             File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 172, in ensure_defaults
>               raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)
>           django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection myapp doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
 The connection myapp doesn't exist
```

This means that the database has not been created yet.

Comment: Yeah something like that. I can't seem to connect to any of the databases that are available. Am i missing some preliminary setup?

Comment: It could easily take up so much of time. The contributing factors could be its a remote connection your working on, and also amount of data your working with,

Comment: that time i actually tried python manage.py inspectdb alone, without the database name. that is why it took so long. 
If i supply the db name, any db that exists, i am getting that error. Looks like i have some problem with my setting.